# Read response headers in Asp.NET Core GRPC client?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I can see that I can easily read headers on server side, write them in response but on client side I see no option how to read headers that are send by server?

Comment: You need to use the async version of the call. From the "call" object, you can then obtain the response headers:  await call.ResponseHeadersAsync() https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/03582c2690176ee1c9362f65e05dc1062054961a/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/AsyncUnaryCall.cs#L87

Comment: Or you can use call.GetTrailers() if what you're looking for are trailers.

Comment: Thanks - it is not intuitive but now I see how to read this